# Is there a way to make function from another class local to current class?

Tags: c++, class

I have a situation where I have to do RenderCommand::render() in Renderer class, But I want to be able to call render() without saying that it's from class RenderCommand:: (so I want something like `using namespace ___`, but for classes), I know I can use define macros and such but it's dirty, this idea is silly but I would like some suggestions (RenderCommand is super associated to Render so it kinda makes sense).

Code:

**[Render Command]**

```
static void RenderCommand::render(VertexArray vao)
{
    bindVAO(vao)
    glDraw(vao);
}
```

**[Renderer]**

```
static void Renderer::renderCircle()
{
    circleShader->use();
    RenderCommand::render(circleVAO);
}
```

Comment: by making it static and accepting arg as class obj?

Comment: Its already static, but what do you mean "accepting arg as class obj"?

Comment: If you wanted some class specific stuff in that function so you can access by using class arg

Comment: This may need a [mre] to see what functions are really static, whether RenderCommand is easily copyable, etc.  You are describing the code, and then commenting to clarify when we imagine your code incorrectly.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, instead of writing `RenderCommand::render(circleVAO);` you want to be able to write `render(circleVAO);`, is that correct? Why? Such shorterning usually tend to make code harder to read and understand and follow along with. Especially if you decide to add multiple overloads or overrides of `render` in different places.

Comment: you are correct, reason is that they are super associated, and I think render() is much easier to read than RenderCommand::render(), tho it could be bit confusing to say where it is coming from.

Comment: Create a (inline) `Renderer::render()` that forwards to `RenderCommand::render`.

Comment: I can do that, but it's bit annoying to write that for every function. (I have 4 functions, render, renderIndexed, renderInstanced, renderInstancedIndexed). it will fill up renderer class